# TYPO3 get BE logged-in user id in tca

Tags: typo3

TYPO3 6.1.3

How to get the logged in user details in ext/myext/Configuration/TCA/mytca.php ?

I am getting `$GLOBALS['BE_USER']` is empty.

I have tried by initializing beuser like this.

```
$BE_USER = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\Bootstrap::initializeBackendUser();
```

Now I get be_user details. 
But the main problem is, if I logout TYPO3, I can not login back!

I have also tried this, but no success (same issue as above)

```
if (!is_object($GLOBALS['BE_USER'])) {
  $GLOBALS['BE_USER'] = t3lib_div::makeInstance('t3lib_beUserAuth');
  $GLOBALS['BE_USER']->start();   // Object is initialized
  $GLOBALS['BE_USER']->backendCheckLogin();
}
```

Comment: usually it is done the other way around: set in User/Group-TSconfig what should be changed for that user. Perhaps you can explain what you want to archive and there is an standard TYPO3 way to do it?

Comment: I wanted to hide that particular record of particular user group. So that record will be listed in select box for some user and not for some other users

Comment: You should use backend permissions for that.

Answer (score -2):

You have to use the backend permission.
Take a look at the [documentation](http://wiki.typo3.org/Backend_user_group_permission_system).